# Writing IPTC data to an image using iptcembed() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to write some IPTC data to an image within an upload form in Codeigniter.

I can get it to read out the data great, but I need to be able to write it too.

Basically when I try and write the data, I get this error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: iptcembed() [function.iptcembed]: Unable to open
>   http://www.mydomain.com/photos/testimage1.jpg
>
> Filename: controllers/upload.php
>
> Line Number: 139

Trouble is, the URL is correct, I don't understand why it can't open the file. The file is uploaded before the iptcembed() is run to ensure that it can find the image.

Line 139 is:

```
$path = base_url()."photos/".$filename;
```

$filename is the filename of the file that is uploaded earlier in the function.

I'm using the first example from the PHP Manual to write the IPTC data.

Ideas?

Comment: Can be a file permission issue?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, but the **file** permission? can the **file** be written to by the user (apache, www-data, whatever) who created it?

Comment: Yes the file is 777 too. I chmod() it to 0777 on upload.

Comment: Actually I can't chmod the file either, I get this error: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory. I don't understand why it can't find the file, it's definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the solution has been found, but just to share.

My problem was the full url, probably in this case

`"$path = base_url()."photos/".$filename;"` the `base_url` is causing that troubles.